# React throwing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. I am following a chapter in book where they load the data from API under `componentDidMount` and update the state of the component as

```
getInitialState: function () {
      return {changeSets: []};
   },
   mapOpenLibraryDataToChangeSet : function (data) {
    return data.map(function (change, index) {
      return {
        "when":jQuery.timeago(change.timestamp),
        "who": change.author.key,
        "description": change.comment
      }
    });
  }, 
  componentDidMount: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://openlibrary.org/recentchanges.json?limit=10',
            context: this,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function (data) {
//             console.log(data);
            var changeSets = this.mapOpenLibraryDataToChangeSet(data);
            console.log("changeSets:" + JSON.stringify(changeSets));
            this.setState({changeSets: changeSets});
        });
    },
```

When I run this, I see error on console as

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at t.render (mikobuf.js:55:41)
    at _renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:17508)
    at _renderValidatedComponent (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:17644)
    at performInitialMount (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:13421)
    at mountComponent (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:12467)
    at Object.mountComponent (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:15:2892)
    at h.mountChildren (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:14:26368)
    at h._createInitialChildren (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:26619)
    at h.mountComponent (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:13:24771)
    at Object.mountComponent (https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js:15:2892)"
```

The running link is http://jsbin.com/mikobuf/edit?js,console,output

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

When I added the `changeSets={data}` while rendering the app, I see data in console

```
ReactDOM.render(<App headings = {headings} changeSets={data}/>, document.getElementById("container"))
```

But I want the data to be pulled from `API`. So as soon as I remove the `changeSets={data}` when rendering, it fails

```
ReactDOM.render(<App headings = {headings}/>, document.getElementById("container"))
```

Comment: Your ajax call is throwing an error: `"error"`. `map` is only defined on arrays.

Comment: According to the information you provide, `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @daydreamer see my answer. You have a couple places where `props` and `state` are used incorrectly. I have the jsbin update and it's now working on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the props `changeSets` when it is actually part of `App`s state.

This:

`<RecentChangesTable.Rows changeSets={this.props.changeSets} />`

Should Be:

`<RecentChangesTable.Rows changeSets={this.state.changeSets} />`

http://jsbin.com/tuqeciyere/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: interesting, the data is passed using state `changeSets={this.state.changeSets}` but child components use it as `this.props` as `<td>{this.props.changeset.when}</td>`. This seems confusing in the first place

Comment: State is internal to a component. Props are what you pass in. If you are passing in data to component you need to use `props`. If you are changing internal state you use `state`. That was a 10 second overview and I'm not the best at explaining things. You use `props` in a child component that receives data from its parent (even if that parent holds onto that data in `state`)

Comment: I think your bin changed from what you first posted. So I'm not sure what the problem is anymore.